# Master public DNS is blank on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to create a clsuter on AWS Elastic Map Reduce.
The Master public DNS for the cluster is empty.

I have the following settings:
1. In the subnet summary corresponding to the cluster I see that---> **Auto-assign Public IP: yes**
2. In the VPC summary corresponding to the cluster I see that ----> **DNS resolution: yes** and **DNS hostnames: yes**
3. I also checked that the VPC corresponding to the cluster is "attached" to an Internet Gateway.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?  If not, please post cluster id (j-####).

Comment: i have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your awscli version. Had the same issue on awscli 1.10.09.
Upgraded to 1.10.30 and it seems to work.